# Why won't my list images align to bottom?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm really not sure what information is relevant to include here, so I'll be generous. On the top of my page, I have a horizontal line. Now, on top of this line, in the bottom right, I want to place my meny which consists of three gif images. The images align to the right nicely but won't go all the way down to the bottom. Earlier, I had the same design but using only CSS to create three boxes and it worked like a charm. The images are exactly 96px wide and 45px high. This is my HTML followed by the CSS (I'm using the 960 grid system):

And oh yeah, I have already tried to use negative margins for the li with CSS.

```
<div class="grid_8">
            <ul>
                <a href="cv.html"><li></li></a>
                <a href="arbete.html"><li></li></a>
                <a href="index.html"><li></li></a>
            </ul>
</div>

ul {
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin-top:50px;
}

li:first-child {
margin-right:-5px;
}

li {
background-image:url('bilder/meny_hem.gif');
float:right;
width:96px;
height:45px;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

EDIT: This is my new code. Correct (?) syntax but the problem remains. See also the image of what it looks like.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="cv.html"></a></li>
    <li><a href="arbete.html"></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html"></a></li>
</ul>

ul {
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin-top:50px;
}

li:first-child {
margin-right:-5px;
}

li {
float:right;
width:96px;
height:45px;
}

a {
display:block;  
background-image:url('bilder/meny_hem.gif');
width:96px;
height:45px;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

[image: The images won't align to bottom line.]

Comment: I'm confused, you're trying to get them to all touch the line? Because right now they are all aligned the same on the bottom.

Comment: Yes, I want them to touch the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that  to stick to the bottom of your container div (grid_8) you'll have to adjust its height to be aproximatelly the height of your buttons like so:

```
<div class="grid_8 container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="cv.html">HEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="arbete.html">HEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">HEM</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.container{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pqV5E/29/

You can also make your `<ul>` absolute and relative to your container and by using bottom:0; you'll have it stick to the bottom like so:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px; 
    right:0;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;      
}
```

If you'll use this last technique please be sure to remove your `<ul>` margin-top, and just add that margin value to your container's height

http://jsfiddle.net/pqV5E/28/

I've used rounded corner buttons instead of images but you can switch to any image you'd like.

Comment: Thanks! I found a different solution though, after a lot of trial and error. I think the problem was that I didn't specify the width and length of the `<ul>` element. When I did, I was able to use `position:absolute` to position the list images to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is not valid HTML:

```
<a href="cv.html"><li></li></a>
```

`<a>` cannot be a direct child of `<ul>`. You need to put the anchor tags *inside* the `<li>` elements.

Then, I would change your CSS so that the `<a>` elements are have `display: block`, have the width and height attributes,  and take the background images. Your `<li>` elements should retain the `float: right` and the width and height attributes and nothing else.

You may have to fiddle with the margin and padding on both the `<li>` and `<a>` elements.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that HTML looked weird. Now all the code is clean and nice, but the problem remains. I've tried to fiddle with both elements but they don't move at all. Could this have to do with the properties of some other element, like ul?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not 100% sure where the black line is coming from based on the HTML, CSS & image you provided but here is a solution that would work:

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/stGPz/

Added the following to your CSS:

```
ul {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    height:45px; /* The height of your li */
}
```

The only other thing I can think of why it's not working is make sure your image is 45px height and the image cover the whole 45px. But this solution gives you a line and has the list items touching that line.